# What is a good combination of tools currently for implementing REST/J2EE/Database + custom auth

Tags: java, authentication, jakarta-ee, rest, openid

Was just wondering at the current point in time, what is a good combination of tools/frameworks/libraries for implementing a REST API on top of J2EE that integrates to a backend RDB and using OpenID for authentication.

What I am looking to implement is a server component that provides a set of services, all of which will utilise OpenID authentication, and the services will retrieve or update information to/from a backend relational database environment.

What I'm interested in are:

```
* application server options available (e.g. Tomcat, Glassfish etc.)
* IDE's (e.g. Eclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJ etc.)
* additional components useful for implementing REST (and JSON payloads)
* what is best practice/good technique/options available for database integration from the services (hibernate via spring, hibernate directly, raw jdbc connections ... )
* for integrating authentication via OpenID - what is an appropriate integration point for any custom authentication mechanism within the J2EE environment - are there any commonly used solutions/plug-ins available for OpenId etc.
```

Also any pointers to good, current tutorials, books etc.

---

Edit:
Unfortunately I haven't had as much time to research the results to this question as I'd have liked.

At this stage I've found that installing/setting up REST with Jersey was very quick and I believe I can use a ContainerRequestFilter to provide the OpenID support as per the article here: http://plaincode.blogspot.com/2011/07/openid-authentication-example-in-jersey.html

I intend on using [OpenId4Java](http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/) for the OpenId support, with the PAPE extensions to get users email address returned.  I don't need OAuth as I don't need to access any of the users other OpenID details or info on their OpenID site from my server app.

I've had a look at the latest Spring, it looks very good and if I were needing to build a web client with my solution, or had more time to look at both, I could easily have ended up leaning that way.

Thanks for the good answers and replies, hard to pick a single correct answer. I've accepted  yves answer because it is correct and the way I'm going at the moment with minimal time to research properly, but awarded the bounty to cfontes answer, as it is also correct, and he's replied with additional information and justification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make it simple and modern (Spring is neither one nor the other for RESTful web-services):

- **Jersey** – the JAX-RS reference – [defines resources](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e41) and [supports OAuth](http://wikis.sun.com/display/Jersey/OAuth); its code is compact, easy to use & to plug to libraries (backends, etc...).

Take a look [at this project on GitHub](https://github.com/yamsellem/Backbone-Jersey), it produces JSON from static data. Its [web.xml](https://github.com/yamsellem/Backbone-Jersey/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml) and [ProductResource](https://github.com/yamsellem/Backbone-Jersey/blob/master/src/main/java/com/xebia/resource/ProductResource.java) are good places to start.

- Every server will do the job, **Jetty** is my favorite, **Tomcat**, the standard
- The choice of an IDE is up to you, the 3 you're giving are great, well integrated with Maven and source control tools. I use **Eclipse** from habit

Comment: While Jersey can be a another solution to the problem, I don't agree with you on Spring MVC not being simple or modern, have you ever used Spring MVC 3 ? it's very straight forward, well supported, very well documented and also RESTful, the focus of jersey is different from Spring MVC as you can see in this article http://www.infoq.com/articles/springmvc_jsx-rs Spring uses JAX-RS standards just as Jersey but try to adapt it to Spring and make it more usable for Web applications rather than web services

Comment: I've used Spring MVC and I agree with Yves. Spring has become pretty bloated over the years.

Comment: Spring MVC can't build RESTful web-services, it uses Jersey for that. So it's an extra layer; way richer but way complex: use it with carefulness. IMO, the « one framework for all troubles » Spring approach is risky. Using little building blocks – [jersey](http://jersey.java.net) & [guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice) in this case – guaranties code's elegance and relevance.

Comment: oops sorry yves - I'll need to research further to verify this, but I awarded the bounty before reading this comment (its late evening in my timezone and didn't want to let the bounty lapse before I got a chance to set it) - seems it can't be undone but I'd need to research before changing anyway.

Comment: I partially agree, if you think like that we should only use JSP and Servlets or write code in C ( as java is a layer above) every tool has it's uses... Spring is there to help you build complex systems abstracting the complexity of things like Depency Injection and other Fixed it did on EJB 2 and 3... For simple things OK go for Jersey it's a Standard it's small and it's always useful to learn the standard but it will become a lot more complex when you try to put all the little building blocks that Spring already did together. Cheers !!!

Answer (score 6):

I would go for

- Spring 3: this can be useful to wire things up with Dependency
  injection and other things.
- Spring MVC: Restful support and Request mapping, a request based
  framework that integrates very well with Spring
- Apache Tiles: to make the HTML templates easier to make.
- Spring Security: it's a JAAS implementation and for me it's better and
  easier than Standard JAAS.( doesn't need a full web server, tomcat will do fine)

This can help you decide which Persistence provider you want : [Persistence Provider comparison](http://terrazadearavaca.blogspot.com/2008/12/jpa-implementations-comparison.html)  I would go for Hibernate, because it have a lot of great features like Criteria API, hibernate Search and it's widely used.

Of course your app should be using JPA 2 for the sake of interchangeability instead of using a Persistence provider directly ( it's not easy to chance from one to another but with JPA2 it's possible, also should be giving you a lot of trouble but it's possible)

Comment: thanks for the reply cfontes.  Which app server setup (e.g. tomcat, jetty, glassfish etc.) would you recommend - also which IDE do you use for development when using these tools?

Comment: probably Tomcat, because it's simpler... but it depends on your requirements. as for IDE the one you are more suited... But to work with Spring I like Spring IDE which is eclipse based, because it  gives you some useful Spring xml editors and other goodies.

Comment: there's a [nice article on ibm devworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-spring3webserv/index.html) about using spring to implement restful web service.

Comment: Here's a [great article](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/) on how to use Spring MVC with JSON/jQuery in an AJAX model. Also, the [sample source](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-ajax/) is available, which will get you running in no time.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with NetBeans 7.0.1 and GlassFish as explained [here](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html)

From the linked tutorial:

> The IDE supports rapid development of RESTful web services using JSR 311 - Java API for RESTful Web Services (JAX-RS) and Jersey, the reference implementation for JAX-RS.

For authentication, I would use the GlassFish JDBC Realm (have a look at [this tutorial](http://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/jdbcrealm_in_glassfish)) but I have never worked with OpenID, so I don't know if this approach can be used together with OpenID.

Comment: netbeans/glassfish seems to be like another logical candidate for the scenario I've described - suprised there isn't more commentary/support for this option.  Have had a quick look at jdbc realm - theoretically I think possible but not sure its the correct injection point for security in the scenario I've got in mind.

Comment: Just to point out in GlassFish 3.1.1 if you need a custom JDBC realm( use your user tables, the one that comes with GlassFish is just an example), you need to build one yourself and use OSGI, I did it a while ago and it was a bit too much work for something so simple( in Jboss for example it's way easier)